# How to copy elements from one drop down list to another dropdown list using javascript inside a popup window?

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdownlist and a button. When I click the button, a textbox alongside another list and 2 buttons will be shown on a popuplist. When the popup closes, the first selection list should get all those values inside the selection list in popup window.

The popupwindow has 2 buttons, one to add to the selection list inside the popup window and another to close the popup window and fill the first selection list.  Also the textbox and selection list inside popup window  should be cleared once I finished adding to the first selection lsit. I'm able to add to the selection list inside the popup window but unable to add the list to the original selection list. Please help as I;m unfamiliar with bootstrap and a newbie to Javascript.

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#newcategory{
    width:200px;
}
</style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="category" multiple size="5" name="category">
    <option value="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="news">News</option>
    <option value="movies">Movies</option>
  </select>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button id="addcategory" onclick="addCategory()" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Category</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Category</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
           <div id="newCategoryWrapper">
        <input type="text" id="newCategoryName" placeholder="New Category name" />
        <select id="newcategory" multiple size="5" name="newcategory" class="newcategory">

  </select>
     </div>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="addonecategory" onclick="addoneoption()">Add </button>


          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="addCategoryButton" onclick="addallOption()">Finish</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var category = document.getElementById("category");
var categoryNameInput = document.getElementById("newCategoryName");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("newCategoryWrapper");
wrapper.style.display = "none"; 
var isAddingNewCategory = false;
var newcategory = document.getElementById("newcategory");
function addallOption() {
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.text = newcategory.value;
  category.add(newOption);
  toggleInput();
}

function toggleInput() {
  if (isAddingNewCategory) wrapper.style.display = "none";
  else wrapper.style.display = "block";
  isAddingNewCategory = !isAddingNewCategory;
}

function addCategory(){
categoryNameInput.value = ""; 
  toggleInput(); 
}

var newcategoryNameInput = document.getElementById("newCategoryName");
function addoneoption(){
     var newOption = document.createElement("option");
     newOption.text = categoryNameInput.value;
     newcategory.add(newOption);
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really a coding service. You should first give it a try and come back with a specific problem. As a start you can check out W3 Schools on [document.createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) which should give you a direction to move in further.

Comment: @ThomasDarvik Can you help me in this issue?

Comment: This is quite a hard task if you do not know Bootstrap and how JavaScript works. I wrote the original code to give you a direction to move in, however, I do not think writing the next code for you will really help you. Try first to understand how HTML layout and JavaScript works. Do some simpler exercises first, and then move to the more advanced tasks :)

Comment: I would also suggest to ask this as a different question. For people coming in and looking at this, they will think the answer I gave you, which you approved is not correct (which is true). Leave the approved question, with the old edits here, and ask a new Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to code works**

1) The wrapper around `input` and the `button` to add a new option to the `select` is added to the code.

2) Using `document.getElementById` I get the `select`, the `buttons` andthe wrapper element around the "editor" used to add options.

3) Using `toggleInput` I set the `display` to hidden or block, depending on the variable `isAddingNewCar` which will toggle the input wrapper, showing or hiding the input field and the button.

4) When the input field is visible, the user will enter a name and press the `addCarButton` which will in turn call the `addOption` function, that will create a `option` element using `document.createElement` and add it to the `select` element using `car.add(newOption)`. After adding the option, the method `toggleInput` is called again to hide the wrapper.

**Note:** The `script` tag has to be under the HTML code to run, but inside the `<html></html>` wrapping the code. In your original code it was outside the `<html></html>` tags.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <select id="car" multiple size="5">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <button id="addbutton" onclick="add()">Add</button>
  <div id="newCarWrapper">
    <input id="newCarName" placeholder="Car name" />
    <button id="addCarButton" onclick="addOption()">Add car</button>
  </div>
  
  
  <script>
    var car = document.getElementById("car");
    var carNameInput = document.getElementById("newCarName");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("newCarWrapper");
    wrapper.style.display = "none"; // default hidden
    var isAddingNewCar = false;

    function addOption() {
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.text = carNameInput.value;
      car.add(newOption);
      toggleInput();
    }

    function toggleInput() {
      if (isAddingNewCar) wrapper.style.display = "none";
      else wrapper.style.display = "block";
      isAddingNewCar = !isAddingNewCar;
    }

    function add() {
      carNameInput.value = ""; // remove old value from input field.
      toggleInput(); // Toggle the visibility of the wrapper of input and button
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As I said, this is not a coding service, so next time try it yourself, and add what you have tried. Hope it helps you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> i have another idea of how the code should be written ...

```js
var car = document.querySelector('#car');
var addArea = document.querySelector('.add-area');

// create the function that gonna do the job for us
function add(){
  // get the input text value
  var inputText = document.querySelector('#input').value;
  // check if the input isnt empty
  if (inputText === "") {
    alert('please fill out the input!');
  } else {
    // create new option element and append it to the select area
    var el = document.createElement('option');
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputText);
    el.appendChild(t);
    el.setAttribute('value', inputText.toLowerCase());
    car.appendChild(el);
    // hide the input
    addArea.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Javascript Exemples</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
</head>
<body>

 <select id="car" multiple size="5">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
 <div class="add-area">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="addbutton" onclick="add()">Add</button>
 </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

i hope it helps!